# Is there a simple way to send POST request using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I need to send some data, `status=1`, to a PHP file on another server that will update a row in a database.

This is what seems to be the way:

```
var data = {
   var1:"something",
   var2:"something else"
};
var querystring = require("querystring");
var qs = querystring.stringify(data);
var qslength = qs.length;
var options = {
    hostname: "example.com",
    port: 80,
    path: "some.php",
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': qslength
    }
};

var buffer = "";
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
       buffer+=chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(buffer);
    });
});

req.write(qs);
req.end();
```

I have to send a simple '1' so there has to be a better way. I have read about the node 'request' library, but I'd prefer not to install another extension for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle), install it using: `npm install needle`.

A simple Post can be performed like this:

```
var needle = require('needle');

var options = {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}

needle.post('http://example.com/some.php', 'status=1', options, function(err, resp) {
  //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice and lightweight library ! (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

```
but honestly for this task I would rather not instal a whole nother extension.
```

The node standard library is designed to be low level, don't be afraid to install modules that abstract the low level stuff away. Most node applications you find will contain loads of small utility modules.

If you are daunted by the complexity of `request` you might want to check out [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) which is a minimalistic http library just like request.